# C# - Get problematic method result by using thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have some kind of data processing, that is depnded on the success of problematic method that returns a result that used in my processing.

The external method is problematic since it works slowly, it may crash and throw exceptions of any type, and I don't have its source code.

I want to use thread in the beginning of my processing to save some time, since my processing is long enough even without that problematic method. but there exists a point that I must have a valid result from the problematic method that I cannot continue if it fails.

I want the use the exceptions of the problematic method in the main thread, so they get the same exception handling as any other exceptions that may be thrown by my processing.

Here is my code - it seems ok and it works, but it just looks too cumbersome to me, so this my question: Is there a better approach to manage correctly the call to the problematic method by thread, and its potential exceptions?

My environment is .NET 3.5, so please I would like to get answers focusing that version, but I would like also to learn if there are new approaches for newer .NET versions.

Thank you very much!

```
public void DoProcess()
{
    object locker = new object();
    bool problematicCodeFinished = false;
    Exception methodException = null;
    Result result;

    Func<Result> getProblematicResult = new Func<Result>(() => problematicMethod()); //create delegate

    //run problematic method it in thread
    getProblematicResult.BeginInvoke((ar) => //callback
    {
        lock(locker) 
        {
            try
            {
                result = getProblematicResult.EndInvoke();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                methodException = ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                problematicCodeFinished = true;
                Monitor.Pulse(locker);
            }
        }
    }, null);

    //do more processing in main thread
    //    ...
    //    ...
    //    ...

    try
    {
        //here we must know what was the result of the problematic method
        lock (locker)
        {
            if (!problematicCodeFinished) //wait for problematic method to finish
            {
                Monitor.Wait(locker);
            }
        }

        //throw problematic method exception in main thread
        if (methodException != null)
        {
            throw methodException;
        }

        //if we are here we can assume that we have a valid result, continue processing
        //    ...
        //    ...
        //    ...
    }

    catch (Exception ex) //for the problematic method exception, or any other exception
    {
        //normal exception handling for my processing
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're making life hard for yourself. Try using tasks from the TPL instead.

Your code would look like this:

```
public void DoProcess()
{
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => problematicMethod());

    //do more processing in main thread
    //    ...
    //    ...
    //    ...

    var result = task.Result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it is not an option for me, since I am in .NET 3.5, and I cannot install external libraries in my environment.

Comment: A pity. Microsoft did to a back-port of the TPL into 3.5. But if you can't use it you can't use it.